# How to translate marker on a geoJSON line in map box gl js using javascript

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I want to translate a marker on the click of a button on a geoJSON line in map box gl js.

I searched a lot but failed to find even a small example which can help me start.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. You will get better answers if you are very specific about exactly what you're trying to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Actually I came up with an answer  which resolved my issue. I will soon post the solution , so it may help others.